# Laravel HTTP client - How to send file

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-api

Thank you in advance,

I have one controller function like

```
public function storeBlog(Request $request)
{
  // Here i am receiving file like $request->file('image');
}
```

Now I want to send that file to an API endpoint like

```
Http::post('http://example.com/v1/blog/store', $request->all());
```

I am getting all the request but not file, I know we need to pass `POST` data as a `multipart` but how that I don't know

can anyone help

Comment: I think you want to store image using api?

Comment: what have you tryed ? what are you using client side, a simple form, Javascript or a mobile device? Have you checked other question related to file upload ?

Comment: see here there is an example of using multipart request li laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client#request-data

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should use Http::attach to upload a file.

```
public function storeBlog(Request $request)
{
    // check file is present and has no problem uploading it
    if ($request->hasFile('image') && $request->file('photo')->isValid()) {
        // get Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile instance
        $image = $request->file('image');

        // post request with attachment
        Http::attach('attachment', file_get_contents($image), 'image.jpg')
            ->post('example.com/v1/blog/store', $request->all());
    } else {
        Http::post('http://example.com/v1/blog/store', $request->all());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer was very helpful but the file content was missing so i have just changed bit your code to 

Http::attach('attachment', file_get_contents($image), 'image.jpg')
              ->post('http://example.com/v1/blog/store', $request->all());
and it is working as expected

Thank you so much

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete answer. Updated answer by your advice. It's a pleasure to help you.

Comment: You can use `$request->file('image')` directly inside `attach` (or use `$image->get()`)